# What game has black dice with keys on three sides?

Tags: identify-this-game

What game are these dice for: black 6-sided dice with a white key symbol on each of three sides with the other 3 sides blank

Comment: Can you add a photo of the dice?

Comment: This will be very hard to answer without a picture.

Comment: What is unclear about this question? It seems fully formed to me. There can't be that many games with dice with blank-blank-blank-key-key-key sides.

Answer (score 3):

They're dice from [Got'Cha! from Milton Bradley](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/15461/gotcha).

Detail of box cover:

[image]

Comment: More detail about why this is the correct answer (such as how the game uses dice with three blank faces and three key-marked faces) would make this a better answer.

Comment: Seems a fine answer to me. Perhaps he’s just trying to reunite a lost part with the game it belongs to